# SELECT to concatenate a N:N relationship in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database, select

I have these 3 tables which put products and their categories in a N:N relationship:

```
products:
product_id | product_name
1          | Apples
2          | Shrimps
3          | Water

categories:
cat_id   | cat_name
1        | Vegetable
2        | Seafood
3        | Fresh
4        | Drinks
5        | Non-alcohol

products_to_categories:
product_id | cat_id
2          | 2
2          | 3
3          | 3
3          | 4
3          | 5
...
```

I would like to `SELECT CONCAT...` to have rows like this:

```
product_id | product_name | product_categories
2            Shrimps        Seafood, Fresh
3            Water          Fresh, Drinks, Non-alcohol
```

Is there a way to do this in MySQL?

Comment: I think that your relation is `N:N` and not `1:N`

Comment: Consider handling issues of data display in the presentation layer/application-level code, assuming you have that (e.g. a simple PHP loop acting upon an ordered array).

Comment: I think that it is that youre looking : ```select p.product_id, p.product_name , CONCAT(p.product_name, ', ', c.cat_name) from products_to_categories pc  JOIN products p  on pc.product_id = p.product_id JOIN categories c on c.cat_id = pc.cat_id```

Comment: @MarcosEchagüe fixed :) ty